# Tangent vectors of a curve in a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold, tangent-spaces

Let (N;$\phi$) be a submanifold of M, such that $\phi(N)\subset M$. Let $\gamma$ : (a,b) -> M be a $C^\infty$ curve such that $\gamma(a,b)\subset \phi(N)$.

### Show that it is not necessarily true that $\dot{\gamma} (t) \in T_{\gamma(t)}\phi(N)$, for each $t\in (a,b)$

Since N is a submanifold in M, $T\phi(N) \subset TM$. Therefore I assumed that the problem needs not to be solved in the choice of $\phi$.
So I intrepreted the question as: find the right curve such that exist at least one $t_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $\dot{\gamma} (t_0) \notin T_{\gamma (t_0)}\phi(N)$.

Has anyone suggestions?

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: You have a typo in the last condition. So the point is that $\phi(N)$ will be an immersed, but not embedded, submanifold.

Comment: Didier: The question comes from an exercise on the book "foundations of differentiable manifolds and lie groups" by Warner. If you mean why I'm asking it, that's because I find it difficult to answer since I expect that the condition posed is indeed necessarily true.
Ted Shifrin: I'm sorry I don't see the typo, can you show me more precisely, please?

Comment: $t=t_0$ on the right hand side. Did you think of an example or two of immersed submanifolds that are not embedded submanifolds?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Actually, I did not. I'll try. Thank you for the hint